# Sails.js not installing on Mac

Tags: node.js

[image]

[image]

Hi I am trying to install Sails.js on a Macbook. For some reason it is giving me this error message and I do not know what is going on. Can someone please show me how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please share error texts with copy/paste... Images are harder to read, and are not visible to google's indexing.

Answer (score 4):

The error says you do not have access...

> EACCES: permission denied

It seems you ran

```
npm install sails -g
```

You should try running this with sudo

```
sudo npm install sails -g
```